# Android translate animation instantly requires full height while animating

Tags: android, android-animation

So imagine you have a parent relative layout with height set to `wrap_content`. Inside this layout is another layout which is hidden by default. This is how I reveal it:

```
view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.translate_in));
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Here is the corresponding anim file. It basically moves the view from the bottom to the top.

```
 <translate
    android:duration="250"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    android:fillAfter="true"/>
```

I expect the parent view to change its height according to the animation of the child view. However when the animation starts the parent view instantly shifts up while the child view is still animating. It feels like the setVisibility is called before the animation has finished.

So to solve this I would scale the height of the child from 0 to 100%, however I do not want a scale but a translate effect.

Any ideas how to approach this problem?

The layout is simple:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundColor="@color/grey">

    <TextView/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundColor="@color/white"
        android:visibility="GONE">

        <TextView/>

     </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It sounds like by "hidden", you mean `GONE`, in which case the parent lays out as though the child isn't there, and will initially have height `0`, but as soon as you set the child to `VISIBLE`, the parent wraps the actual height of the child, and "instantly shifts up". Yeah?

Comment: @MikeM. there is really nothing special to the layout. See my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    final RelativeLayout parent = null;//parent relative layout
    final View child = null;//parent relative layout child

    final int initParentHeight=parent.getHeight();

    parent.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            parent.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

            int finalParentHeight = parent.getHeight();//get parent final height
            final ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = parent.getLayoutParams();
            ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(initParentHeight, finalParentHeight);
            animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    layoutParams.height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                    parent.requestLayout();//animate height change
                }
            });
            animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    layoutParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;//reset parent layoutparams height to wrap_content
                    parent.requestLayout();
                }
            });
            animator.setDuration(250);
            animator.start();
            return true;
        }
    });
    child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: It should return false so that it doesn't do the first draw.

Comment: I know this is old, but it'd be nice to have some context on what this code does