# How to start multiple FlutterActivities?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have an app made in Flutter that runs only in Android and it has one screen that is made entirely in Native code.

Now a new request from the Project Manager is to include a button on that native screen that opens a new page. I want to make that page (activity) entirely in Flutter but I can't make it work in any ways I tried.

This is how the app looks:
Flutter page(MainActivity) -> Native page (another activity) -> **A new flutter page (a third activity)**

**THE APP IS NOT AN EMBEDDING APP, IT IS A FULL FLUTTER APP WITH JUST ONE NATIVE PAGE**

Does anyone know how to do that?

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [versÃ£o 10.0.17763.379], locale pt-BR)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.3)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.30.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Can't you swap out the views?

Comment: What you mean? can you show me a sample?

Comment: Kinda like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36775658/2413303

Comment: Wont work, because the native page is a full activity, not just a view.

Comment: Are you 100% sure of this? Looks like [just a View to me](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/66fdeb163ef6fed6e9bac652bb36c7495aa17fb8/shell/platform/android/io/flutter/app/FlutterActivityDelegate.java#L163). Of course, it'd be easier to animate it if it weren't the ContentView, but if it existed inside a FrameLayout, if able. I wonder if `FlutterFragmentDelegate` exists. If not, it doesn't seem to hard to write it, though.

Comment: Couldn't you just "fake" it? finishing the native view, and returning to the flutter activity, but change the state of the flutter app to appear as if it's been launched by the button press? Otherwise, take a look at the [guide to add flutter to an existing app](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps). `View flutterView = Flutter.createView(
      MainActivity.this,
      getLifecycle(),
      "route1"
    );`

Comment: @herbert I tried creating another FlutterActivity, but for some reason the plugins stoped working, the SharedPreferences for example, it returns empty values everytime I try to get something from it.
Also, for some reason my "Flutter" java class has no methods called "createView".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key was the `GeneratedPluginRegistrant` that was causing the issues. Now I could make it work like this:

```
class ANewFluterActivity : FlutterActivity() {

    override fun createFlutterView(context: Context): FlutterView {
        val matchParent = WindowManager.LayoutParams(-1, -1)
        val nativeView = this.createFlutterNativeView()
        val flutterView = FlutterView(this, null as AttributeSet?, nativeView)
        flutterView.setInitialRoute("YOUR_NEW_ROUTE")
        flutterView.layoutParams = matchParent

        this.setContentView(flutterView)
        return flutterView
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this) //THIS IS THE SECRET TO MAKE PLUGINS WORK PROPERLY
    }

}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that whis will start a new Engine, so, there is a loading time for that.