# Android Bottom sheet dialog dynamic content animation

Tags: java, android

I have added a fragment to the bottom sheet dialog and when the bottom sheet dialog pops up, I replace the fragment. While changing the fragment, I want to change the height with animation without closing the dialog. How to make animation?

I want like this animation. When replace content in bottom sheet

This link :
[Implementing transitions in a BottomSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55929366/implementing-transitions-in-a-bottomsheet)

Comment: Finally I found the answer. To avoid the blinking in the first drawing, set true to false.Thx so much #drivfe ,#Jiang Qi
The solution is at this address: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36775658/11840484